Excel VBA Macro: Problems with CodeName
here the code:
Function Update_online(version As Integer, modules_input As Variant, sheets_input As Variant)

    Dim toName, fromName As Workbook
    Dim FromVBProject As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim ToVBProject As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim OverwriteExisting As Boolean: OverwriteExisting = True
    Dim Answer As Boolean
    Dim sheet As Variant
    Dim module As Variant
    Dim module_list As Variant
    Dim sheets_list As Variant
    
    
    'vediamo cosa c'è da aggiornare
    module_list = Split(modules_input, ";")
    sheets_list = Split(sheets_input, ";")
    Debug.Print Now
    MsgBox "New version available, I'm going to download " & UBound(module_list) - LBound(module_list) + 1 & " modules and " & UBound(sheets_list) - LBound(sheets_list) + 1 & " Sheets", vbOKOnly
    Debug.Print "Aggiorno i moduli: " & modules_input & " e i fogli:" & sheets_input
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set toName = ThisWorkbook
    'Inizio a canellare i fogli che non mi servono
    
    For Each sheet In sheets_list
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = toName.Worksheets(sheet)
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Attenzione!!! Il foglio " & sheet & " non è stato trovato!!"
            GoTo Error
        Else
            If toName.Worksheets(sheet).ProtectContents Then toName.Worksheets(sheet).Unprotect Password:="mypassword"
            toName.Worksheets(sheet).Visible = xlSheetVisible
            toName.Worksheets(sheet).Delete
            Debug.Print "Ho cancellato il foglio " & sheet
        End If
        Set ws = Nothing
        Set ws = toName.Worksheets(sheet)
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                GoTo Error
            Else
                Debug.Print "Foglio " & sheet & " cancellato con successo"
        End If
    Next
    Set fromName = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="link to external file")
    
    For Each sheet In sheets_list
        fromName.Worksheets(sheet).Copy After:=toName.sheets(toName.sheets.Count)
        Debug.Print "Ho copiato il foglio " & sheet & " dal file di rete"
        Set ws = Nothing
        Set ws = toName.Worksheets(sheet)
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Attenzione!!! Il foglio copiato " & sheet & " non è stato trovato!!"
            GoTo Error
        Else
            If toName.Worksheets(sheet).CodeName <> sheet Then Debug.Print "PROBLEM!!!!!!!!!"
            Debug.Print "Foglio " & sheet & " copiato con successo"
            
        End If
    Next
    
    'Ora copio i moduli
    
    Set FromVBProject = fromName.VBProject
    Set ToVBProject = toName.VBProject
    
        
    For Each module In module_list
        Debug.Print "Aggiorno il modulo " & module
        Answer = CopyModule(CStr(module), FromVBProject, ToVBProject, OverwriteExisting)
        If Answer Then
            Debug.Print "modulo " & module & " aggiornato con risposta:" & Answer
        Else
            Debug.Print "problemi dell'aggiornamento del modulo " & module
            GoTo Error
        End If
    Next
    
    'Non mi serve più, chiudo il file esterno
    fromName.Close


    'Metto a posto i codename

    Debug.Print "sistemiamo i codename"
    For Each sheet In toName.Worksheets
        toName.VBProject.VBComponents(sheets(sheet.Name).CodeName).Name = sheet.Name
    Next
    
    Debug.Print "elimino la protezione da tutti i fogli"
    
    For Each sheet In toName.Worksheets
        If sheet.ProtectContents Then sheet.Unprotect Password:="mypassword"
    Next
    
    
    Debug.Print "elimino tutti i link esterni"
    newLink = toName.FullName
    LinkSources = toName.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
    If IsArray(LinkSources) Then
        For Each link In LinkSources
             toName.ChangeLink link, newLink, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
        Next
    End If
    Debug.Print "link esterni eliminati"
    
    
    Err.Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Call Initiate
    Exit Function
Error:
    Debug.Print "Update non riuscito"
    fromName.Close
End Function


Hi all,
I'm trying to create an auto-update funciton for a local xls file, this function source modules and sheets from an online version of the file to update a local version.
it accepts a list of modules and sheets and basically do the following:

delete the local sheets i would like to update
open in the same Excel istance the source file
copy the sheets i would like to update from the online repository
update the modules
update the external link references of copied sheets

all is working quite good while I'm experiencing randomic problem with the codename of the sheets.
During the copy process sometimes the codename is copied correctly, while sometimes the codename is changed to codename1 (like the codename already used in the workbook)
If I run the function 1 time work correctly, second time not, than again correctly.
Seems like the project structure is not updated correctly while the macro is in execution, I also tried to add a block to rework the codename of the sheet but it doesn't work

"I also tried to add a block to rework the codename of the sheet but it doesn't work" Maybe include that code and explain exactly what "didn't work" looked like?
